# Meshlab non-dispersed vertex Coloring

Tags: colors, 3d, vertex, meshlab

In meshlab, If I select *a* vertex and color it with red (per vertex color function), the result becomes

[image]

Red is *too* dispersed.

What I want is just : (image below was edited by photoshop):

[image]

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

On triangular meshes, when the color is defined in a per-vertex way, the colors are linearly interpolated across each triangle, so the result is precisely the expected one.

If you need just a way of looking at a few vertices, just enable the visualization of selected vertices and select them.

On the other hand, if you just need to reduce the color's spread, refine the mesh so that the underlying triangles are smaller, and the color is interpolated across a smaller area.

Comment: Refining mesh will help, but then the object gets (unwanted) more vertices and more faces. Am I understanding correctly ? It seems there is no option to adjust the degree of color spread to nearby face area.

Answer (score 0):

You can get something quite similar to your desired behavior.

1. The color dispersion is due to Gouraud shading. You can disable it clicking in the tab of face render options and change color button from "vertex" to "face" or "user defined"
2. To render vertex as "balls with color"

- Click on the tab of vertex and choose the option `Dot Decorator` (1)
- Change the size of dots with the `Point Size` Bar (2)
- Let the color buttons in "mesh", not "user defined"

[image: Dot decorator]